# Как быть с col-xl-12 в Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток.

Можно как-то расширить сетку Bootstrap? Самая большая ширина 1170px `.col-lg-` но много шаблонов не соответствуют это ширине, то есть у меня макет 1200px, а сетка Bootstrap 1170px

Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно на [странице настройки Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-3.ru/customize.php#container-sizes) в поле `@container-large-desktop` указать необходимый размер.

В вашем случае подойдёт `((1170px + @grid-gutter-width))`, при условии что сумма отступов `@grid-gutter-width` указана как `30px`.